# Find a statistic that is a function of $U$ and $W$ and unbiased for the parameter $\theta = 2\mu -5\sigma^2$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, sampling

Let $X_1 , X_2 ,...,X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution, $X_i \backsim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and define $U = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$ and $W= \sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_{i}^2}$.

(a) Find a statistic that is a function of $U$ and $W$ and unbiased for the parameter $\theta = 2\mu -5\sigma^2$

(b) Find a statistic that is unbiased for $\sigma^2 + \mu^2$

My question about this problem is the following: Is it necessary to use the transformation theorem to do this, that is, can't this exercise be solved without having a prior concept about the transformation? If so, then what would be the best way to start? or how to apply the theorem in this case in such a way that an unbiased statistic is obtained for $ \theta $ in part (a) and another for part (b)? I appreciate some help to do this.

Comment: I suspect it might be useful to know expressions for $E[U], E[W], E[U^2]$

Comment: An unbiased estimator based on $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)$ is equivalent to an unbiased estimator based on $T=(\overline X,S^2)$ where $\overline X=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ is sample mean and $S^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline X)^2$ is sample variance. This immediately gives unbiased estimators of $\mu,\mu^2,\sigma^2$ based on $T$, which is all you need.

Comment: @StubbornAtom If $T_1 , T_2, ..., T_n $ are estimators of $ \theta_1 , \theta_2 ,..., \theta_n$ respectively, then their linear combination $a_1 T_1 + a_2 T_2 + ... +a_n T_n$ is an estimator for $a_1 \theta_1 + a_2 \theta_2 +...+ a_n \theta_n$?

Comment: Linearity of expectation says $E[a_1T_1+\cdots+a_nT_n]=a_1E[T_1]+\cdots+a_nE[T_n]$ if all expectations exist.